# How to show shadow around the dial in activity gauge chart?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I am using highchart plugin to draw charts in a website.I need dark black shadow around the dial. I am attaching image what I have done and what I need to achieve. The left image is a real graph and right one is the image which is the target. I need to make both identical.

Comment: This is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/virendra656/0wLLhrea/12/ .

Comment: I would recommend doing some research on SVG filters. There are no attributes within Highcharts to apply a shadow to an activity gauge as in your example. My suggestion is to build and apply a filter to the rendered SVG image after the chart is loaded.

Comment: In the Highcahrts you can call shadow() function on SVG elements, but it will create something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9xpr3gxp/

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot it worked like a charm.I did research for almost a day. I wish I could buy you a beer.